# expressjs: Sending a file from parent directory

Tags: javascript, express, sendfile

I would like to use expressjs's sendfile to send a file from a parent directory of the script file. What I tried to do is this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('../../index.html');
});
```

I get a forbidden error because apparently, sendfile does not trust path traversal. So far I've been unable to figure out how to change the directory for files sent via sendfile. Any hints?

Edit: I was kind of tired when posting this, in fact it is kind of easy. I'll leave it here in case anybody else stumbles upon this. There's an option parameter for sendfile that allows you to do just that, like so:

```
app.get( '/', function( req, res ){
    res.sendfile('index.html', { root: "../../"});
});
```

Comment: For static resources on server, you can also use `express.static`. Ideally sendFile function is for serving files (client downloads file) not for static content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to mention root as the second parameter of `sendfile()`.

For example:

```
app.get('/:dir/:file', function(req, res) {
  var dir = req.params.dir,
      file = req.params.file;

  res.sendfile(dir + '/' + file, {'root': '../'});
});
```

You can find more details here:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1465

Comment: Fwiw, realizing it's nearly a decade later, "_The signature '(path: string, options: any): void' of 'res.sendfile' is deprecated._" Have not googled yet, but fyi.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `express.static`.

Say you have the following directory set up:

```
/app
   /buried
       /deep
           server.js
   /public
       index.html
```

Then you should have the following Express configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express.createServer();
server.configure(function(){
    server.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../public'));
});
server.listen(3000);
```

`res.sendfile` is meant for "finer-grain" transferring of files to the client. [See API docs for example](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile).

Comment: the `configure` method doesn't seem to exist in Express 3

Answer (score 3):

parent folder:
    -app
        -routes.js
    -index.html
In the above case, Add the following code to routes.js to send a file from parent directory.

```
var path=require("path") //assuming express is installed 

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../index.html'));
});
```